# Why can't my terminal use the command "django-admin"(my system is windows and I have added path to the environment)

Tags: django, development-environment, python-venv

My terminal and cmd cannot identify the command "django-admin" in any folders. However, when I use the terminal inside pyCharm, it functions normally.
Can someone help me with the problem and explain why it happens? Thanks a lot.

I have added paths to my environment.
[image]

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that there is a folder called `Scripts` inside your project means that you are using a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) on Windows OS. In this case probably created automatically by your IDE (PyCharm).

You cannot use the command on CommandPrompt/PowerShell because your system cannot find `Django`. Its installed inside this virtual environment, which is apart from your OS. PyCharm is probably automatically activating this `venv` when you open your project and thus that is the reason why you can issue commands form inside the IDE.

Naturally, you manually activate it:

```
> cd C:\Users\86177\pythonProject
> .\Scripts\activate
(venv) > django-admin
```

`(venv)` indicates that the environment is activated. Note that usually `Scripts` is inside a folder called `venv`, the commands I've written are based on the paths on your image.